# angularfire login with a previously issued firebase token

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I am using a separate server that authenticates my angular app.  As part of that process the server has already authenticated the user with firebase and has received an auth_token back.  Once the angular app is served, I re-request the token from my server and now I want to issue an angularFireAuth.login().

I have tried this but get a "Reference Error unrecognized auth".  Am I missing something very fundamental?  Shouldn't I be able to login with a pre-existing firebase auth_token??

Here is the code:

```
    var profileController = function ($rootScope, $scope, $log, $location, angularFire, angularFireAuth, profileService) {
    init();

    function init() {
        $scope.profile = {};

        profileService.getFirebaseToken(function success(data) {
                $scope.auths = data;$
                $scope.auth = $rootScope.auth;
                var id = {'id': data['_id']};
                auth=angularFireAuth.login(data['access_token'],id);
                $scope.auth = auth;
            }, function error(err) {
            console.log('error', err);
        });
```

** Note:  data['_id'] = string id that is the userid in my firebase and used as auth.id in my security rules
          data['access_token'] = string token.  this is not a dictionary or object. just the string token returned from:  token = create_token(SECRET, custom_data, options).  Which runs successfully on my python tornado server using the: firebase_token_generator module.

Comment: Please, add your example auth code to jsfiddle. Perhaps you are not fully configured firebase auth account or your application.

Comment: Before I create a fiddle let me post the code:

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I figured it out.  The error I was receiving because the login request is asynchronous.  So the "Reference Error: auth" was because the variable auth was referenced before assigned. 
I did not ultimately use this exact code above.  So I do not know if it was/would work.  Instead I switched to the construct that is on the firebase site:

```
   fbLoginService.getFirebaseToken(function success(data) {
        var dataRef = new Firebase('xxxxxx.firebaseio.com')
        dataRef.auth(data['firebase']['access_token'], function(error) {
          if(error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
            alert("Login Failure.  Unable to login to database(firebase)");
          } else {
            console.log("Firebase Login Succeeded!");
            $rootScope.firebaseAuth=true;
          }
        });
    }, function error(err) {
        console.log('error', err);
        alert('error', err);
    });
```

I have now created a loginController and loginService that I fire on initial load of index.html with the inclusion of the ng-controller="fbLoginController".   All looks good so far.